# How can I right align the icon in v-text-field and change the color?

Tags: vue.js, icons, vuetify.js, textfield

I have a vue.js application with Vuetify. I have a couple of v-text-fields that look like this:

[image]

I would like to do 2 things:

1. Move the icons to the right.
2. Change the color of the icons.

There are suggestions on stackoverflow for how to do this but nothing worked in my case so I'm looking for some fresh ideas.

This is how the first v-text-field is implemented:

```
          <v-text-field
            slot="activator"
            v-model="date"
            label="Date"
            prepend-inner-icon="$vuetify.icons.calendar"
            :rules="[(v) => !!v || 'Date is required']"
            required
            readonly
            outline
          ></v-text-field>
```

This is how the second v-text-field is implemented:

```
    <v-text-field
      slot="activator"
      ref="text-field"
      clearable
      :label="label"
      :value="content"
      :prepend-inner-icon="showIcon ? '$vuetify.icons.clock' : ''"
      readonly
      outline
      :rules="[v => required == null || !!v || label + ' is required',
        v => !isInPast || pastValidationMessage,
        v => !startAfterEnd || startAfterEndValidationMessage]"
      :required="required"
      @click:clear="onClear()"
    ></v-text-field>
```

It would be nice to also be able to change the color of the outline. That too I've found answers to but none that actually worked in my case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [prepend](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#prepend) slot instead of the prop:

```
 <v-text-field label="Date">
          <template #prepend>
            <v-icon color="blue" right>
              mdi-calendar
            </v-icon>
          </template>
  </v-text-field>
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/YzGBwde)